# Bluetooth speaker will not connect Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth, dell

I'm running a Dell XPS 15 7590 and boot Ubuntu 22.04.2. When I look at Bluetooth Settings, I can see my bluetooth speakers and open the dialog for that device. I can remove it, but I cannot connect to it. It briefly allows the device to "Connect" but immediately goes off again. I have two speakers that work this same way.

How can I diagnose this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up messing the whole bluetooth stack up. It became masked. I had removed and reinstalled bluetooth several times. Finally when I unmasked, enabled and started bluetooth it worked again. I'm not sure how. But this is solved for now.
This website might have helped: https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-bluetooth-connectivity-issues-in-ubuntu/